# usage of 88 level under FILLER field

Tags: cobol

Does it make sense to have 88 level under FILLER declaration, like in this code:

```
 10   FILLER   PIC X(02).
      88  SOME-NAME  VALUE 'XX'.
```

Can this field SOME-NAME be used in the program?

Comment: @SimonSobisch Thanks for the explanations / clarifications. All is good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that makes totally sense. You may use this for:

- only (or mostly) set / check by field condition-name  - `SET SOME-NAME TO TRUE` and `IF SOME-NAME`; as Scott Nelson pointed out this is a good way to prevent use of "magic values"
- have the value stored and somewhere referenced by the group field, most likely the `01` above your `10`.

Comment: I do something similar in my code.  I don't want to have "magic values" that other programmers use, e.g. IF ACTION-CODE = "A2" or MOVE "A2" TO ACTION-CODE, but rather use the 88 mnemonic name, eg. IF ACTION-ADD-CONDITIONALLY, and SET ACTION-ADD-CONDITIONALLY TO TRUE.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are being sarcastic or not, @Simon Sobisch, but, yes, I found your answer to be spot on.  I just wanted to add _why_ someone might do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 10   WS-SOME-NAME-AREA PIC X(02).
      88  SOME-NAME     VALUE 'XX'.
```

If you give that area a name, it will not be long before some other programmer decides to do this:

```
 Move 'ZZ' to WS-SOME-NAME-AREA
```

Or maybe this, almost well intentioned, but still wrong:

```
 Move 'xX' to WS-SOME-NAME-AREA
```

And then your program will behave in wildly unpredictable ways.

So if you don't name the storage, they really have to work to mess up your condition names.  Which is why I never name storage for condition names if I can at all help it.